# Showing distinct columns having a max rowcount

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL scheme `visits(name, vdate, vtime)` which represents a snapshot of all guests in a house. I want to list the busiest days -- i.e., the ones with the most visitors. So from

```
john | 2000-01-01 | 13:00
adam | 2000-01-01 | 13:00
cary | 2000-01-01 | 13:00
joan | 2000-01-01 | 15:00
mary | 2000-01-01 | 15:00
kate | 1950-11-11 | 02:00
```

The ideal output would be

```
2000-01-01 | 13:00 | 3
1950-11-11 | 02:00 | 1
```

I can produce an output that also lists `2000-01-01 | 15:00 | 2`, but I don't want that; I just want the max number of rows for that date: 3.

The base code is:

```
SELECT vdate, vtime, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM visits GROUP BY vdate, vtime ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I've tried SELECT DISTINCT vdate (it does not change the results at all). I think what may be is needed is some second query which uses the MAX function, but I am not sure how to word it.

Comment: MYSQL MAX: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-max-function.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses variables and only one aggregation:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*,
             (@rn := if(@vd = vdate, @rn + 1,
                        if(@vd := vdate, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select vdate, vtime, count(*) as cnt
            from visits
            group by vdate, vtime
           ) v cross join
           (select @vd := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by vdate, cnt desc
     ) v
where rn = 1;
```